# Can noreply email address get replies?

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, imap

I created a bounced mail tracking system in Laravel. It works like this:

1. Every time an outgoing email is bounced, mailer-daemon from google notifies the source (i.e. replies) about the bounced email.
2. I tracked my inbox using Weblex-imap and hence was able to track all the bounced emails.

The problem is, now what if I have to set up a noreply email address. Can it still get replies from mailer-daemon about the bounced emails? Or will the inbox be empty and my system won't work?

Comment: There is nothing special about noreply. It is just an informal claim that the address' owner won't pay attention. People can make false claims.

Comment: The answer is, it can.